# RestSharp RestRequest with Paramaters not working

Tags: parameters, get, restsharp

I'm making a call to a web api.
Exmaple is supposed to retrieve every organisation with the letter 'a' in the name.
This is the url, and it works directly against the web api http://localhost/GMSWebServices/api/Organisations/get?name=a

If i hard code the Source into my calling function like this

```
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("Organisations/Get?Name=a");
        // set the response data format
        request.RequestFormat = ReturnFormat;

       var response = _restClient.Execute<List<string>>(request);
```

This works fine.  But when i use the format where the source is a variable and paramaters are added differently
eg

```
string Source = "Organisations";
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Source, Method.GET);
        // set the response data format
        request.RequestFormat = ReturnFormat;
        //provide any paramaters
        foreach (RestSharp.Parameter p in WebParamaters)
        {
            request.AddParameter(p);
        }
var response = _restClient.Execute<List<string>>(request);
```

It does not work.

Am i using the Paramaters in the correct way?
And do i need to append "/Get" to the end of my Source I assumed the Method.Get took care of that.

How should i be calling the source Get method with the paramaters in my list ?
What should my routing template look like for each method to work ?

Erick

Comment: That's a one-liner with [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/): `var response = await url.AppendPathSegment("Organisations/get").SetQueryParam("name", val).GetJsonAsync<List<string>>(); `

Answer (score 2):

Ok ..so I couldn't get AddParameter to work but then I changed it to AddQueryParameter and it worked.

I had a look at the Restshapr documentation but I'm unsure why one works and the other doesn't.

I'm calling a .net web api service but it ignores the Parameters property in the RestSharp request object. Maybe web api doesn't support this method of sending parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append "/get", the Method.GET only specify the request type, and doesn't add anything to url, (because sometimes you want a get method requesting a url that doesn't have "get" in it).

The usage of parameters seems right, so just change to that:

```
string Source = "Organisations/get";
```

or if you use Source in other places without get:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Source + "/get", Method.GET);
```

Comment: @user1413844 is you p looks like this:  p.Name = "name" and p.Value="a"?